# Pros/Cons of not using the prototype chain and returning objects instead

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm starting to understand javascript, but are there any benefits of using javascript objects like so ...

```
var Person(name, age) {
    var obj = {
        species: "Homo sapien",
        location: "Earth"
    };
    obj.name = name;
    obj.age = age;
    return obj;
}

var Mike = Person("Mike", 17); // => { ... name: "Mike", age: 17}
```

versus the standard

```
var personProtoype = {
    name: "anon",
    age: 0,
    species: "Homo sapien",
    location: "Earth"
}

var Person = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype = personPrototype;

var Mike = new Person("Mike", 17);
```

because it seems to use less code and easier to implement and understand.  "Inheritance" is also pretty straightforward with the first method too.

```
var Student(name, age, major) {
    var obj = Person(name, age); // => { ... name: name, age: age}
    obj.major = major;           // => { ... name: name, age: age, major: major}
    return obj;
}
```

I understand that the following doesn't use prototype chains at all, just functions that simply construct objects. I was just wondering if there was any benefit of doing things this way? Maybe to have objects that don't look back at a huge chain of prototypes? (if that type of behavior is ever desired)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Might i suggest you try a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+prototype+vs+this+object). There are already a lot of great answers for this question on SO. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript) is probably what you want. Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Sorry about that, I'll be sure to check more thoroughly next time, but I think the answer below is what I was looking for :) Thanks!

Comment: You might be happy about the class syntax coming in ES6: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t think of any advantages beyond the ones you listed, although there may be some. Here are some of the disadvantages:

1. **No `instanceof` testing.** Using the `Person` implementations in your question, slightly renamed:

   ```
   var Mike1 = Person_no_prototype("Mike", 17);
   var Mike2 = new Person_with_prototype("Mike", 17);
   console.log(Mike1 instanceof Person_no_prototype);    // false
   console.log(Mike2 instanceof Person_with_prototype);  // true
   ```
2. **When methods exist, uses more memory.** Consider an implementation of a `greet` method, put on either `obj` or `Person.prototype`:

   ```
   /* obj or Person.prototype */.greet = function greet() {
       alert("Hi there, " + this.name + "!");
   };
   ```

   Using a prototype, the `greet` function is created only once. Without a prototype, you create a new function each time, with whatever overhead that implies.